# PointCloud.FindPlane stops working after a while

Tags: android, google-project-tango

Hi I am working with the google tango and the unity SDK! I am making an app were you are supposed to align yourself in a 3D model of a building. With the following code you are supposed to be able to point the tango towards a wall and click on that wall in the 3D model to align them through PoinCloud.FindPlane and Physics.Raycast. This works very well! But. It only works in the beginning of the app run. Because of some reason PointCloud.FindPlane always fails after about 30 seconds of the apps runtime.

I am not using arealearning or area description since this is supposed to compensate for the drifting that arealearning otherwise is supposed to solve.

I have tried alot of things like using arealearning etc. but it doesn't work anyway. I suspect that something gets corrupted in the PointCloud when it takes to many points, however I have no clue on how to fix it. I have had this bug for about 6 months now and hoped it would be fixed in a later update, but it didn't.

I think this also happens in one of googles own examples which I based this code on.

If anyone has any idea of what is happening and is causing the problem or if you have some way to refresh to point cloud once in a while since it always works for some seconds that would be great! Or perhaps use FindPlane on only the latest poses since I only use FindPlane right in front of the tango. Thank you!

Something worth mentioning is that I am not "scanning" very throughly with this app. Just walking through the room.

(Edit) I also read that to use FindPlane the tango is checking every point in the point cloud and should only be used once per frame. So maybe it gets to slow after a while? Then I need to refresh the PointCloud once in a while but I can't seem to find any way to do that.

```
public class ModelPositionRefiner : MonoBehaviour, ITangoLifecycle, ITangoDepth
{


    /// <summary>
    /// The tango gameObject to ray cast from.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject m_virtualTangoDevice;

    /// <summary>
    /// The HAX fixed distance between the tango and the bim floor.
    /// </summary>
    public float m_tangoToFloorDistance;

    /// <summary>
    /// Position in model to align with point cloud interception.
    /// </summary>
    private Ray m_selectedEnvironmentSurface;

    /// <summary>
    /// The point cloud object in the scene.
    /// </summary>
    public TangoPointCloud m_pointCloud;

    /// <summary>
    /// The canvas to place 2D game objects under.
    /// </summary>
    public Canvas m_canvas;


    public Text m_errorField;
    public TouchEffect m_touchEffect;
    public TouchEffect m_errorTouchEffect;
    public TouchEffect m_loadingTouchEffect;

    /// <summary>
    /// If set, then the depth camera is on and we are waiting for the next depth update.
    /// </summary>
    private bool m_findPlaneWaitingForDepth;


    /// <summary>
    /// A reference to TangoApplication instance.
    /// </summary>
    private TangoApplication m_tangoApplication;

    /// <summary>
    /// Unity Start function.
    /// 
    /// We find and assign pose controller and tango applicaiton, and register this class to callback events.
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        m_tangoApplication = FindObjectOfType<TangoApplication>();

        m_tangoApplication.Register(this);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the permission granting process is finished.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="permissionsGranted"><c>true</c> if permissions were granted, otherwise <c>false</c>.</param>
    public void OnTangoPermissions(bool permissionsGranted)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when succesfully connected to the Tango service.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnTangoServiceConnected()
    {
        m_tangoApplication.SetDepthCameraRate(1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when disconnected from the Tango service.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnTangoServiceDisconnected()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called each time new depth data is available.
    /// 
    /// On the Tango tablet, the depth callback occurs at 5 Hz.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tangoDepth">Tango depth.</param>
    public void OnTangoDepthAvailable(TangoUnityDepth tangoDepth)
    {
        // Don't handle depth here because the PointCloud may not have been updated yet.  Just
        // tell the coroutine it can continue.
        m_findPlaneWaitingForDepth = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unity destroy function.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        m_tangoApplication.Unregister(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unity Update function.
    /// </summary>
    public void Update()
    {
        UpdateCheckForManualRefining();
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for a manual click to align the bim surface clicked with the
    /// </summary>
    private void UpdateCheckForManualRefining()
    {
        // Check so that we don't click UI. The first is for computer and the 0 is required for which touch on touch device.
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() || EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(0))
            return;

        Vector2 clickPosition;

        if (Input.touchCount != 1)
            return;
        clickPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

        // Add a progress animation when pressing to refine position.
        if (Utils.PressTimePassed(1f) && !Utils.PressDistancePassed(20))
        {
            m_loadingTouchEffect.Apply(m_canvas, clickPosition);
        }
        // When pressed enough time align clicked bim object with wath the tango is pointing toward!
        if (Utils.PressTimePassed(2.5f) && !Utils.PressDistancePassed(20))
        {

            RaycastHit hitInfo;

            // 10 is the environment model layer.
            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(clickPosition), out hitInfo, 1000, 1 << 10))
            {  
                m_selectedEnvironmentSurface = new Ray(hitInfo.point, hitInfo.normal);
                m_touchEffect.Apply(m_canvas, clickPosition);
                StartCoroutine(_WaitForDepthAndCorrectModel(clickPosition));
            }
            else
            {
                m_errorTouchEffect.Apply(m_canvas, clickPosition);

            }
        }
    }


    private IEnumerator _WaitForDepthAndCorrectModel(Vector2 clickPosition)
    {
        m_findPlaneWaitingForDepth = true;

        // Turn on the camera and wait for a single depth update.
        m_tangoApplication.SetDepthCameraRate(TangoEnums.TangoDepthCameraRate.MAXIMUM);
        while (m_findPlaneWaitingForDepth)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        m_tangoApplication.SetDepthCameraRate(1);


        // Find the plane.
        Camera cam = Camera.main;
        Vector3 cloudOrigin;
        Plane plane;
        if (!m_pointCloud.FindPlane(cam, new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0), out cloudOrigin, out plane))
        {
            m_errorField.text = "Error: Tango has no depth. Valid distance: 0.5m - 4m. \nThe surface can't be too bright or too dark.";
            m_errorTouchEffect.Apply(m_canvas, clickPosition);
            yield break;
        }

        //cloudNormal is correctly oriented
        Vector3 modelNormal = m_selectedEnvironmentSurface.direction;
        Vector3 cloudNormal = plane.normal;


        float floorLimit = 45;
        float ceilingLimit = 180 - floorLimit;

        float modelAngle = Vector3.Angle(modelNormal, Vector3.up);
        float cloudAngle = Vector3.Angle(cloudNormal, Vector3.up);

        // 0 is floor, 1 is ceilling, 2 is wall.
        int modelNormalType = modelAngle < floorLimit ? 0 : (modelAngle > ceilingLimit ? 1 : 2);
        int cloudNormalType = cloudAngle < floorLimit ? 0 : (cloudAngle > ceilingLimit ? 1 : 2);

        if (modelNormalType != cloudNormalType)
        {
            m_errorField.text = "Error: If you click on a wall, floor or ceiling the Tango must be facing the same.";
            m_errorTouchEffect.Apply(m_canvas, clickPosition);
            yield break;
        }
        //Input is valid, reposition.
        m_errorField.text = "";

        //We can't click a floor or ceiling and rotate around the Y axis.
        if (cloudNormalType == 2) // && modelNormalType == 2
        {
            //Ignore X and Z rotation since the floor is expected to be parallell with the worlds.
            modelNormal.y = 0;
            cloudNormal.y = 0;


            float angle = Vector3.Angle(modelNormal, cloudNormal);
            Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(modelNormal, cloudNormal);

            angle = angle * Mathf.Sign(cross.y);



            //We use cloudNormal since the new Model is now expected to be cloudNormal.
            Location.ShowingLocation.Environment.transform.position += Vector3.Project(cloudOrigin - m_selectedEnvironmentSurface.origin, cloudNormal);

            Location.ShowingLocation.Environment.transform.RotateAround(cam.transform.position, Vector3.up, angle);
        }
        else //Preferably a floor.
        {
            //Only move us to the right height from the floor.
            Location.ShowingLocation.Environment.transform.position += Vector3.Project(modelNormal, cloudOrigin - m_selectedEnvironmentSurface.origin);
            //Move us to the pointed direction.
            //Location.ShowingLocation.Environment.transform.position += planeCenter - m_selectedEnvironmentSurface.origin;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Trionet, I could reproduce this issue with the UnityAugmentedReality sample app (if that's the app you are referencing to?). I suggest you try to keep depth framerate always at TangoDepthCameraRate.MAXIMUM to see if that address this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I *can't reproduce this.. have you tried my suggestion?